# Send bulk SMS in twilio using C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, twilio-api, bulksms

I need to know how do I send a bulk SMS using Twilio API and C#.I did some research which also show that I need to use Twilio’s Passthrough API, but I fail to understand it. Here is the code I compiled:

```
const string accountSid = "xxxxx";
const string authToken = "xxxxx";

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

MessageResource.Create(to: new PhoneNumber("+27" + txtTo.Text),
                       from: new PhoneNumber("xxxxx"),
                       body: txtMessage.Text,
                       provideFeedback: true,
                       statusCallback: new Uri("http://requestb.in/1234abcd"));

MessageBox.Show("Message sent successfully");
```

Comment: What happens when you execute this code?

Comment: The code runs properly. But I want to compile a code to send multiple numbers(recipients)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this way. You have to **loop through your subscribers** list and send it one by one or by using a [parallel foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var subscriber = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            {"+3912345678", "John"},
            {"+3917564237", "Mark"},
            {"+3915765311", "Ester"}
        };

// Iterate over subscribers
foreach (var person in subscriber)
{
    // Send a new outgoing SMS by POSTing to the Messages resource
    MessageResource.Create(
        from: new PhoneNumber("555-555-5555"), // From number, must be an SMS-enabled Twilio number
        to: new PhoneNumber(person.Key), // To number, if using Sandbox see note above
        // Message content
        body: $"Hello {person.Value}");

    Console.WriteLine($"Sent message to {person.Value}");
}
```

Comment: How could I make the Dictionary list to be on one textbox and be able to send multiple numbers using one textbox

Comment: @Marcus insert comma or ; separetes values in the textbox then use one or more split () to get an array to insert in the dictionary. Like John Doe: +001212456789; first split (';')  to get rows then a second split(':') on each row to get name and number.